# Mocking static class function in jest doesn't work

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Given a very basic javscript class

`Foo.js`

```js
export default class Foo {
    static bar() {
        console.log("bar");
    }
}
```

how can I mock the bar function?

Here is what i thought should work (but isn't):

`Foo.test.js`

```js
import Foo from "./Foo.js";

it("test", () => {
    jest.mock("./Foo.js"); // mock Foo class
    const myMock = jest.fn(); // create a new mocking function
    Foo.prototype.bar = myMock;

    Foo.bar();

    console.log(myMock.mock.calls);
});
```

But then `Foo.bar()` call in the test calls the original function (so "bar" get logged) and `console.log(myMock.mock.calls);` prints a empty list, so the mocking function istn used.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class was mocked after it was imported, the mock doesn't affect it. `jest.mock` should be either moved to top level so it could be hoisted before `import`, or in case the class doesn't need to be mocked for the whole suite, `import` should be placed inside a test and possibly replaced with `require`.

`bar` method isn't mocked because it's static method but it's prototype method that was mocked. Methods shouldn't be mocked by assignment because this prevents them from being restored.

It should be:

```
jest.spyOn(Foo, 'bar').mockImplementation(() => ...);
```

It should preferably be restored with `jest.restoreAllMocks()` or `restoreMocks` configuration option to not affect other tests.